# Creating settings files with custom names and locations

Tags: c#, settings

I am in need of a custom settings file. I cannot use the one in Visual Studios as it doesn't allow you to change the name or location of the file. I have searched and have not been able to find any way to create settings files, in xml format without using the Visual Studios or ways to implement them. Could someone point me in the right direction? I am using Windows Forms on .Net 4.5

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question, you're basically just asking how to store/retrieve values from a file.

Here's an example of how to save/load settings from an XML file:

http://www.picnet.com.au/blogs/guido/post/2009/09/10/xml-settings-files-no-more-web-config

Answer (score 0):

try to create an instance of XmlSerializer class to serialize your settings to the stream, and write this stream to file.